# Add event and reminder not working in 6.0 marshmallow

Tags: android, events, calendar, reminders

I am facing on weird issue.
I am trying to add events in `calendar` and also `reminder`. It's working fine in all devices except the one having `Marshmallow - 6.0`

When i try to add events, it also returns me event id here. And even though i am getting event id here, `I can not see events added in my calendar`

```
   ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        event.put("calendar_id", 1);
        event.put("title", "Match");
        event.put("description",PTGConstantMethod.validateString(match.getMatch_name()));
        event.put("eventLocation", match.getVenue());
        event.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        event.put("dtstart", startDate.getTime());
        event.put("dtend", endDate);

        event.put("allDay", 0); // 0 for false, 1 for true
        event.put("eventStatus", 1);
        event.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true

        Uri eventUri = context.getApplicationContext()
                .getContentResolver()
                .insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, event);
        long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
```

I am adding reminder here,

```
        ContentValues reminders = new ContentValues();
            reminders.put("event_id", eventID);
            reminders.put("method", CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
            reminders.put("minutes", minutes);

            context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
                    .insert(Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminders);
```

But app crashes while adding reminder. Here are my logs.

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
>   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)
>   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
>   at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
>   at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1231)

In my build.gradle

```
  minSdkVersion 14
  targetSdkVersion 22
```

I finally found that there isn't any calendar with    `event.put("calendar_id", 1);`. So how could i get app default calendar?

I tried by adding new calendar and add events to that.

```
        ContentValues calendar = new ContentValues();
    calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)+" Calendar");
    calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, true);

    Uri uri = context.getApplicationContext()
            .getContentResolver()
            .insert(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI, calendar);
    long calendarId = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

But i am not able to see this calendar in my calendar app. When i try to add events using this new calendar. Events get display but on click of event, my default calendar app gets crashed. What i am doing wrong while adding new calendar to default calendar app? Thanks.

Comment: Marshmallow requires permission from the user, its a new feature introduced starting from Android M. Implement permission manager to grant access and do it.

Comment: Yes. I am aware about it but it is if my target sdk is 23 right? But my target sdk is 22.

Comment: Whatever, but u are debugging directly to Marshmallow right? so if marshmallow sdk is utilized the code also need to alter to its supportive to work

Comment: But if it is the reason then i should check for another permission too like camera,Gps and other. But those functionalities are working fine. So i was confused. Let me try by checking permissions once.

Comment: I don't think it's permission issue in 6.0 . Have checked both permission for calendar  and it is granted .

Comment: refer this https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/0UZ8JR7bL1U

Comment: did you solved the problem iam facing the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for posting answer in such a way,but what I found while adding event manually in Android M calendar, it says that we need to add account to calendar account in order to add events. So I am guessing that unless and until we do not add or map a calendar to at least one account, we cannot add events manually or programmatically to Android M device calendar.

Comment: How can I solve it programmatically? I'm having the same issue of @Beena but on a user device, and so I cannot force him/her to configure an account.

Answer (score 0):

Try below link:

[How to add multiple event to android marshmallow Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361574/how-to-add-multiple-event-to-android-marshmallow-calendar)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use inside Fragment.

At first use:

```
super.requestPermissions( new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

Inside fragment, you need to call:

```
FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(permissionsList, RequestCode)
```

**Note:**

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity, permissionsList, RequestCode);
```

add this library in gradle for FragmentCompat class .

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:version_of_library'
```